# Problem putting axes labels at the correct position

Tags: pgfplots

I can't seem to find the fault behind my axes labels not appearing where I want them to be. I want 'x' to be right of the x-axis and 'y' to the above of y-axis. I tried 'current axis.right of origin', 'current axis.above origin' as well as 'ticklabel* cs'. Nothing seems to work. What am I missing?

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xlabel=$x$,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
    ylabel=$y$,
    every axis y label/.style={at={(ticklabel* cs:2)},anchor=south},
    axis lines=middle,
    domain=0:5.5,samples=100]
\addplot[
name path=line1,
color=blue]{x^2};
\addplot[
name path=line2,
color=violet]{2^(-x)};
\end{axis}
\fill[draw,name intersections={of=line1 and line2},red](intersection-1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `axis lines=middle` redefines `every axis x label/.style` and `every axis x label/.style`. You must set both styles after `axis lines=middle`:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=middle,
    xlabel=$x$,
    every axis x label/.style={at={(current axis.right of origin)},anchor=west},
    ylabel=$y$,
    every axis y label/.style={at={(current axis.above origin)},anchor=south},
    domain=0:5.5,samples=100]
\addplot[
name path=line1,
color=blue]{x^2};
\addplot[
name path=line2,
color=violet]{2^(-x)};
\end{axis}
\fill[draw,name intersections={of=line1 and line2},red](intersection-1) circle (2pt);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah I see now! Didn't thought the order matters in this  case.

Answer (score 2):

1. you use ancient `pgfplots` (version 1.9). Please use/upggrade it to recent one (now is version 1.18.1),  which you call by `\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}`.
2. axis label style, to what you like to have, you can simple define by

   ```
    xlabel style={right},
    ylabel style={above},
   ```

Complete MWE with some small changes of your code is:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.18}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    axis lines=center,
    xlabel=$x$, ylabel=$y$,
    xlabel style={right},
    ylabel style={above},
    domain=0:5.6,samples=100]
\addplot[name path=line1, color=blue]{x^2};
\addplot[name path=line2, color=violet]{2^(-x)};
%
\fill [name intersections={of=line1 and line2, by=a}, 
       red, semitransparent] (a)  circle [radius=2.4pt];
\end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]